# Pandas sqlite3: DataFrame.to_sql. "Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type"

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, pandas-to-sql

I am learning to use pandas and sqlite together. The idea is to read a pandas DataFrame, modify it, and create a sqlite database.

this is my code :

```
import sqlite3

# create my database
conn = sqlite3.connect('my_db.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

# create a DF from csv file 
my_df = pd.read_csv('my_csv_file.csv', sep = '\t')

# this DF contains 72 columns, called VN[REAL], where N is between 0 and 71. The values are floats.

# create a list concatenating two columns 
my_list = list(my_df['V1[REAL]']
my_list.append(list(my_df['V2[REAL]'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(my_list)
df2.to_sql("Values", conn, index=False, dtype='float')
```

and I get the error :

```
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

What could be the source of the error ?

Comment: You need column names in df2. Right now it reads numeric values, 0, 1, 2,.. And use SQLAlchemy for `to_sql`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to scape character the brackets []